# Whenever i put input value it print double value in javascript CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, readline

So i made a program called connect four, it take input from user to place a piece in selected grid but whenever i press value it print double like e.g. i press "a" it show "aa".

```
let current_player = 1 ;
let chosen_column;
 const answer = await new Promise(resolve => {
        io.question(`Player ${current_player}, enter a column to place a piece in: `, resolve)
    });
    chosen_column = answer;
```

[click here to see the problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSDuU.jpg)
here you can see it show double, anybody can help to solve this problem?

Comment: User-typed text appears in the console, make sure you don't repeat it yourself

Comment: i don't repeat it by myself, i just press the single value but it shows double